# Gedmo Slug from relation as suffix

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need to generate the slug from a related field as suffix, but I'm only able to do it as prefix. I've configured SlugHandler as following:

```
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=90, unique=true)
     * @Gedmo\Slug(handlers={
     *      @Gedmo\SlugHandler(class="Gedmo\Sluggable\Handler\RelativeSlugHandler", options={
     *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="relationField", value="category"),
     *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="relationSlugField", value="name"),
     *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="separator", value="-"),
     *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="urilize", value="true"),
     *      })
     * }, fields={"title"})
     */
    private $slug;
```

That code creates the following slug: "category-name-title", but I need it as "title-category-name".

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: I never used Gedmo Slug but have you tried to change the order of the handler options?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do it with existing handlers. But you can always create and use your own custom `RelativeSlugHandler`

```
class MyRelativeSlugHandler extends RelativeSlugHandler {
    public function transliterate($text, $separator, $object) {
        // change this method implementation as you like
    }
}
```

In annotation replace `class` with the path to your custom `MyRelativeSlugHandler`